# Split CSV File into two files keeping header in both files

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I am trying to split a large CSV file into two files. I am using below code

```
import pandas as pd

#csv file name to be read in
in_csv = 'Master_file.csv'

#get the number of lines of the csv file to be read
number_lines = sum(1 for row in (open(in_csv)))

#size of rows of data to write to the csv,

#you can change the row size according to your need
rowsize = 600000

#start looping through data writing it to a new file for each set
for i in range(0,number_lines,rowsize):

    df = pd.read_csv(in_csv,
          nrows = rowsize,#number of rows to read at each loop
          skiprows = i)#skip rows that have been read

    #csv to write data to a new file with indexed name. input_1.csv etc.
    out_csv = 'File_Number' + str(i) + '.csv'

    df.to_csv(out_csv,
          index=False,
          header=True,
          mode='a',#append data to csv file
          chunksize=rowsize)#size of data to append for each loop
```

It is splitting the file but its missing header in second file. How can I fix it

Answer (score 1):

`.read_csv()` returns an iterator when used with `chunksize` and then keeps track of the header.  The following is an example.  This should be much faster since the original code above reads the entire file to count the lines, then re-reads all previous lines in each chunk iteration; whereas below reads through the file only once:

```py
import pandas as pd

with pd.read_csv('Master_file.csv', chunksize=60000) as reader:
    for i,chunk in enumerate(reader):
        chunk.to_csv(f'File_Number{i}.csv', index=False, header=True)
```